# While installing extension Readiness check fails in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, extensions, installation

[image: fails]

**PHP Version** 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Mysql version : 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 
(Is mysql version is one of the issues ? as[Magento requirement](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html) prefer mysql 5.6.5–5.6.x )

I am trying to activate the plugin from admin panel on **localhost**.

Comment: have you got a solution?

Comment: I install usually using the composer or manual process in both the cases i don't find these issues. In readiness check, most of the time it fails and I think it depends on server configuration and settings.

Answer (score 0):

To activate the module please go to your installed magento directory /app/etc/config.php . In your config file you find your module set to 1 , it is activated else if it is 0 , you need to revert it to one.

```
return array (
'modules' => 
 array (
  'Vendor_Module' => 1,
  'Vendor_Module' => 1,
```

but before that you need to execute the command from your terminal

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: in app/etc/config.php module name is not mention.

Comment: 1. Place your module fiels in app/code/Yourmoduel files

Comment: 1. Place your module files in app/code /Yourmodulefiles  
 2. Open terminal and cd /path/to/your/magetno/installation  
 3. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 
 then check if you can see the module in app/etc/config.php hope this will help

Comment: is it a right way to install a plugin as this has to be done by compiler ?

Comment: yes ,  no worries

Comment: ok, when i extracted the extension it has some folders and some files unser the folder name `somename-somename-1.0.4`

Comment: i have to create app\code\here_goes_all_folder_and_fils       `its a third party extension `

Comment: The folder structure should be like app/code/Companyname/Modulename/
remove the version name 1.0.4

Comment: Autoload error: Module 'SOMENAME_Banners' from '/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/somename/banners' has been already defined in '/var/www/html/magento2/vendor/somename/banners'

Comment: after deleting app/code/SOMENAME folder , i compile it again now extension is activated and same is shown in config.xml file